# "Изрисовал" — так говорят?

Tags: лексика, стилистика

Говорят "изрисовал"? Если да, то в чем разница слов изрисовал и разрисовал?

Comment: Можно сказать "изрисовал". Это слово есть в словарях. А разница между *изрисовал* и *разрисовал* настолько тонкая, что объяснить ее не берусь.

Answer (score 2):

**РАЗРИСОВАТЬ**, св. кого-что. 1. Покрыть, украсить рисунками, расписать (красками, фломастерами и т.п.).
**ИЗРИСОВАТЬ,** св. что. Покрыть что-л. сплошь рисунками.

**Разница в том,** что в первом случае художник занимает под свой рисунок  всю поверхность, а во втором поверхность сплошь покрыта рисунками и  письменами, не обязательно связанными друг  с другом.

Михаська взглянул на заиндевевшее окно и увидел, что мороз очень занятно **разрисовал** стекло. [Альберт Лиханов. Чистые камушки (1967)]

Он дома так **разрисовал печь,** что все дивились. [Василий Шукшин. Чудик (1967)]

И всю эту страницу **разрисовал** расходящимися от заглавия красивыми завитушками, а загибы их украсил маленькими листьями. [В. В. Вересаев. Воспоминания (1925-1935)]

Однажды Дирак читал лекцию по квантовой механике, **изрисовал** всю доску и под конец спросил: [Коллекция анекдотов: институт (1970-2000)]

Скоро я всю камеру **изрисовал** вдоль и поперек и под разными углами во всех направлениях. [Анатолий Ким. Белка (1984)]

Но иногда эти слова **могут быть синонимами**, причем глагол ***изрисовать*** более экспрессивен.:

А потом он и плато вокруг **изрисовал (= разрисовал)** всякими диковинными фигурами и мордами да еще и оплел их орнаментом дорожек, нравились тогда Данилову индейские примитивы. [Владимир Орлов. Альтист Данилов (1980)]

Comment: Можно ли сказать, что для выражения негативного отношения используется именно *изрисовал*?

Comment: Да, возможно, здесь есть какая-то коннотация, и определяется она в каждом случае по контексту.

Answer (score 0):

Диапазон слова *изрисовал*: от покрытия рисунком всех возможных (в том числе) не предназначенных поверхностей, мест и предметов до порчи их же минимальным по трудозатратам чирканьем на самом видном месте. Последнее не предполагает особой квалификации рисовальщика.